# Does asp.net can capture Url param as Variable like flask?

Tags: asp.net

for example, flask can get param in url:

```
".com/<name>/<token>"
```

get 'name' and 'token' as Variable .

Does asp.net can do this?

Answer (score -1):

You can use attribute routing in ASP.Net Web API and should use the `Route` attribute

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetSomething/{name}/{token})"]
public MyResponse GetSomething(string name, string token)
{
    ...
}
```